# How to read Retrofit response in Repository pattern with Coroutines

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, repository-pattern, kotlin-coroutines

I am currently following an MVVM and Repository Architecture tutorial in Android, and because of the abstractions in the tutorial codes I came across, there are some things I don't understand.

Although the code works fine (compiles without any issue), the abstraction makes it hard for me to understand how to handle Retrofit responses.

Repository

```
suspend fun login(username: String, password: String) { // LiveData<List<AuthModel>> {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val auth = Network.retrofitInstance?.create(AuthService::class.java)
        val i = auth?.doLoginAsync(username, password)?.await()
        if (i != null) {
            database.authDao.updateAuthInfo(*i.asDatabaseModel())
        }
    }
    //return auth
  }
}
```

Interface

```
interface ServiceSectionDao{
  @POST("login")
  fun doLoginAsync(
    @Query("user_id") userName: String,
    @Query("password") passWord: String
  ): Deferred<NetworkAuthContainer>
}
```

Retrofit Object

```
object Network {

 private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
 private val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8081/api/"

 val retrofitInstance: Retrofit?

 get() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            var client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(RequestInterceptor())
                .build()

            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .build()

        }
        return retrofit
    }
```

Request Interceptor

```
class RequestInterceptor : Interceptor {
 var token = "FmQ54sSLm0H0P83EFU7fB2k9flgs5fXQNBS7EgtH";

   fun Token(token: String) {
     this.token = token;
   }

 override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    var request = chain.request()

    if (request.header("No-Authentication") == null) {
        //val token = getTokenFromSharedPreference();
        //or use Token Function
        if (!token.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val finalToken = "Bearer " + token
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", finalToken)
                .build()
        }
     }
     return chain.proceed(request)
  }
}
```

What I get from above val i = auth?.doLoginAsync(username, password)?.await() is already a NetworkAuthContainer, I don't have a chance to check for any HTTP status code.

During debug I can see a **result** object returned by Retrofit, but I am not able to process it because I do not know where in the code I am supposed to read the values should it be on the RequestInterceptor, or Repository(login) and how?

Answer (score 0):

First problem with your code is that you are using deprecated [CoroutineCallAdapterFactory](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter), starting from version 2.6 [Retrofit now has native support for kotlin suspend functions](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05). so first thing that you should do is update your `Retrofit` depenency to latest version.

Once you do that, then you will be able to update your `doLoginAsync` to

```
@POST("login")
suspend fun doLogin(                    // use of suspend modifier
    @Query("user_id")  userName: String,
    @Query("password") passWord: String): NetworkAuthContainer     // no need to use Deffered
```

Now to get `HTTP` status code from response you can update the return type of `doLogin` to `retrofit2.Response<NetworkAuthContainer>` and in your repository

```
 val response = auth!!.doLoginAsync(username, password)    // This is HTTP response
 if (response.code() == 200) {
     // To get NetworkAuthContainer call body()
     database.authDao.updateAuthInfo(*response.body().asDatabaseModel())  
 }
 else{
      // Handle different response codes
 }
```